# Subdirectory Angular app in Firebase hosting

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, firebase-hosting

Have been trying to deploy my angular app within a sub-directory `/grid` but nothing shows up [here](https://columns.firebaseapp.com)

1. For the index.html, I've added `<base href="/grid/" />`
2. For the firebase config, I've used

   ```
   "rewrites": [ {
       "source" : "/grid/**/*",
       "destination" : "/grid/index.html"
    } ]
   ```
3. For the angular config,

   ```
   angular.module('columns', [
     'ui.router',
     'columns.main',
   ])
   .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
      'use strict';

      $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

      $stateProvider
        .state('main', {
          url: '/',
          templateUrl: '/columns/main/main.html',
          controller: 'MainCtrl'
        });
      });
   ```
4. And the build will have

   ```
    module.run(['$templateCache', function($templateCache) {
      $templateCache.put('/columns/main/main.html','<something>');
    }]);
   ```

If I run it locally and change the base tag to `<base href="/" />`, it will works fine. Anyone see the error?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are still looking, I just came across your question while searching for it myself.

You can have a sub-folder in your firebase hosting(public) directory called "/grid" and the correct rewrite rule would be :

```
"rewrites": [ {
  "source" : "/grid/**",
  "destination" : "/grid/index.html"
} ]
```

That is without the extra "/*" at the end.
From your config it seems you have only provided the rules for your angular app, you need to may also need to set appropriate prefix rules to your angular router as well.

Hope it help :)